# Does Linux have a Ctrl+Alt+Del equivalent?

Tags: linux, ctrl-alt-delete

Does Linux have a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> equivalent?

Comment: CTRL+ALT+DEL can do many things on Windows? Are you looking for a process manager?

Comment: This varies a great deal by what kind of system you are using. What distribution/desktop environment/window manager do you use?

Answer (score 26):

X can be killed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd>, and if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or F2 through 6), you'll be dropped to a virtual console where you can type commands to kill the bad app. To switch back to the GUI, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: Might need to hit Alt+SysRq+R before you can use Ctrl+Alt+F1, if the keyboard is stuck in some strange mode.

Answer (score 11):

Well you can create shortcut for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> in Linux, but there is some other more interesting combinations that you might like to know.

Holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>SysRq</kbd> (which is the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key) and typing <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> with a few(I usually count to 5) seconds between each key will get you safely restarted. <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> will do a shutdown rather than a restart. As pointed out by a comment, this is not a single command, but a combination of many commands, each doing a specific thing. So I recommend to take a look at [REISUB - the gentle Linux restart](http://kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/) for more details.

And you might already know this but press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + any of the keys from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> to get a console at any time, which you can use to login in text mode and use command line. This was very helpful when I messed my desktop environment.

Comment: Downvoted. Define "slowly", or explain what `reisub` **really** does. This is not a single command, but a combination of 6 commands, each of them doing something specific (look up the Wikipedia article on *magic SysRq key* for details). So if you hit `i` too quickly after `e`, you can kill the programs while they're still shutting down - like I did after reading this answer.

Comment: Edited the answer, hope this clarifies the confusion.

Comment: Whether REISUB works, depends on the contents of file `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`. It may be disabled altogether, or some functionalities may be disabled. For example, I had some machine where Ubuntu MATE 18.04 was often freezeing, and it turned out that in the default configuration of that system only B of the REISUB actually worked.

Comment: To follow on from @raj — In Ubuntu (and therefore derivatives), for example, all but the `B` have been disabled. I don't know why, though.

Answer (score 10):

Under GNU/Linux [at least those based on the [SystemV init style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style)], the behavior of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> relies on the configuration file `/etc/inittab` where you should be able to read a line like:

```
<id>::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t3 -r now
```

(example from an ArchLinux distribution) which means that the system will be shutdown when it receives the key combination. But you may want to do something else, like[*](http://xkcd.com/149/):

```
<id>::ctrlaltdel:/usb/bin/sudo make me a sandwich
```

(which is much more useful :)

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `me'.  Stop.

Comment: @Eroen `/usb/bin/sudo` file not found.

Comment: SystemV-style init is not used by most distributions anymore.

Answer (score 5):

**The Linux kernel can either hard reboot or send SIGINT the init process upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>**

Therefore, if the SIGINT behaviour is enabled, then you can make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> do whatever your init wants it to do.

The Linux kernel itself allows two possible behaviors from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>:

- reboot immediately
- send SIGINT to the init process

Which behavior is used can be selected with either:

- `reboot` system call, see `man 2 reboot`
- `/proc/sys/kernel/ctrl-alt-del`

For example, BusyBox' 1.28.3 init execs an arbitrary command given in `/etc/inittab` as:

```
::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot
```

And here is a minimal interesting C example for uclibc:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/reboot.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "cad\n", 4);
    signal(sig, signal_handler);
}

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    /* Disable the forced reboot, enable sending SIGINT to init. */
    reboot(RB_DISABLE_CAD);
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is [an easy setup to try this out](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/fde15ac9216d07c2769ab91e05abc64214f73a05#ctrl-alt-del).

On Ubuntu 20.10 for example, which uses systemd as the init, everything is wired up so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> by default offers to log you out on the GUI. [How can I give a grace period to CTRL-ALT-DEL in systemd](https://superuser.com/questions/1512011/how-can-i-give-a-grace-period-to-ctrl-alt-del-in-systemd) suggests that this is controlled by `/lib/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target`, but on my system that is just a symlink to `reboot.target`, which seems to actually reboot, not just logout. Maybe someone more patient than me can figure out exactly what is going on.

Comment: This is the answer I came here for, thank you so much! <3

Answer (score 3):

In the Linux console, by default in most distributions, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> behaves as in the MS-DOS - it restarts the system.

In the GUI, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> will kill the current X server and start a new one, thus behaving like the SAK sequence in Windows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>).

Comment: The second part is simply false. Killing the X server will immediately terminate the active session, and all active programs with it. This is nowhere *near* what ctrl+alt+del does in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, however the action it takes depends on desktop manager configurations. In KDE it shows a dialog for which you can choose if restart or halt the system.

Answer (score 2):

[REISUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#.22Raising_Elephants.22_mnemonic_device) would be the closest equivalent. Magic SysRq keys are the only way of emulating traditional Windows / DOS hard-resets in Linux / UNIX.

For a Program Manager-like interface, use top and hit 'k' for 'k'ill.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is disabled by default in X Servers > 1.6 (although some distros re-enable it in the config files that they ship). Although it doesn't do what Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> does in general killing X and fixing misbehaving programs is preferred over restarting the machine.

Comment: +1 for magic SysRq-keys. They have been handy many times in the past.

Comment: Whether REISUB works, depends on the contents of file `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`. It may be disabled altogether, or some functionalities may be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same keys as on Ubuntu but they may vary according to your distribution.

Comment: That's not true. This will mostly reboot the window manager, not open up a task manager.

Answer (score 0):

In gnome, there's a feature called "Keyboard Shortcuts" that lets you customize keyboard shortcuts.

The process manager for Gnome is called gnome-system-monitor, so if you go to:
 - System;
 - Preferences;
 - Keyboard Shortcuts and add gnome-system-monitor as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> it should work for you :)